# What are the tables monitor_* for?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, mariadb

In my database I have the following tables, and I don't know where they come from and what are they used for.

```
monitor_config                    
monitor_log                       
monitor_servers                  
monitor_servers_history           
monitor_servers_uptime            
monitor_users                     
monitor_users_preferences         
monitor_users_servers
```

I am using MariaDb with Docker and AWS. Is it some king of automaticly generated tables by one of the components ?

Many thanks !

Comment: tables in the "information_schema", "performance_schema", and "mysql" database are installed by default. In which database did you find the tables you list ?

Comment: In my website database, not in the special ones `information_schema`, `performance_schema` or `mysql`

Comment: What third party software are you using?  What monitoring software?  (They may have come from AWS.)

Comment: I think those tables were created a long time ago, and were just not deleted after system update. (The last logs were insert a few years ago). I don't think that they are created by AWS (I don' actually know that monitoring software we are using currently, but the one we are using isn't using those tables) Thank you guys for you help anyway, I mark this question as solved.